With jq, how do I delpath a path in an array?
I am trying to fetch some JSON, delete some paths, and return the result. I can do this:
kubectl get deploy my-deployment -o json | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[].imagePullPolicy'

and I get back a value. Notice that "containers" is an array. But I want jq to filter out "imagePullPolicy" from any containers objects that are returned. I tried this, but it doesn't work:
kubectl get deploy my-deployment -o json | jq '.|delpaths([["spec","template","spec","containers[]","imagePullPolicy"]])'

I also tried writing "containers" without the brackets following it, which didn't work. How can I do this? What am I doing wrong? I want to delete "imagePullPolicy" in any containers object it appears in.
